# Add a barcode field to Product Inventory in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, inventory

I would like to add a Barcode Field under my SKU code field in my Inventory settings of my Product. I'd like to use this as I'm working with WooCommerce POS and based on the barcode field I could do a scan, but still use the SKU fields for the real SKU codes.

How can I accomplish this without the use of any plugins. (Read: Function.php code).

I already tried using the following code, but without any success:

```
//Add barcode to the product inventory tab
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data','add_barcode');
function add_barcode(){
    global $woocommerce,$post;
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_barcode',
            'label'       => __('Barcode','woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => 'Scan Barcode',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __('Scan barcode.','woocommerce')
        ));
}
//Save Barcode Field
function add_barcode_save($post_id){
    if(isset($_POST['_barcode'])){
        update_post_meta($post_id,'_barcode',sanitize_text_field($_POST['_barcode']));
    }else{
        delete_meta_data($post_id,'_barcode',sanitize_text_field($_POST['_barcode']));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta','add_barcode_save');
//Set POS Custom Code
function pos_barcode_field(){return '_barcode';}
add_filter('woocommerce_pos_barcode_meta_key','pos_barcode_field');
```

As the code just doesn't seem to have any effect at all when added to the Functions.php. I'm using the Fruitful theme if that changes anything.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for the help you could provide me!

Comment: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-barcode-isbn/

Comment: No, I'm scanning the products so the number that comes from this like 123456789 will then be put into this field. I don't have to generate my own barcodes as all my products already have unique barcodes.

And I'm searching for a way to do it without the need of plugins. I also do not need it on my front-end, just for the backend to quickly scan and pay a product in store.

Comment: So it seems my code actually does work, if it's added as a separated plugin, but not when added to the Function.php from the theme Fruitful, it doesn't seem to work.

It either returns a 500 error or just doesn't function correctly.
Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be regarding this? I've yet to modify anything else to the functions.php of this theme and I tried to put it at the total end or start without any luck either.

Comment: This should absolutely be a plugin because it is custom functionality whereas themes should handle "display". But also themes are loaded after plugins so some of the WooCommerce action hooks you are hooking into may have already been fired by the time your `functions.php` is run.

Comment: @helgatheviking

Thanks for the information, then it was a good idea to isolate the code in the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned above, your code should be a plugin. Here's your code updated for WooCommerce 3.0. It isn't backcompatible though.

```
function add_barcode(){
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_barcode',
            'label' => __( 'Barcode', 'your-plugin' ),
            'placeholder' => 'Scan Barcode',
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'description' => __( "Scan the product's barcode.", "your-plugin" )
        )
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data','add_barcode');


function add_barcode_save( $product ){
    if( isset( $_POST['_barcode'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_barcode', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_barcode'] ) );
    } else {
        $product->delete_meta_data( '_barcode' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'add_barcode_save' );
```

Then anywhere you need to retrieve the meta data, you can do so like this:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product->get_meta( '_variable_billing' );
```

Comment: I'm still using WooCommerce 2.6 as I'm afraid to update to be honest with all the problems I've seen users have with the 3.0 version.

But thanks either way for your answer for people who did actually upgrade to 3.0!

Comment: You will have to upgrade eventually. :) WooCommerce 3.0.5 should be released soon so all the point releases are fixing bugs and making it better. But it was still a major release and not all themes/plugins were ready. I highly recommend building a development site to test the upgrade on first before going into production.

Comment: Yea definitely, will do that once we decide to actually move to the newer versions. Currently everything works fine so as long as it does then we're good for now. If everything will be compatible in the end, then we'll consider upgrading!

Either way thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Alright this is rather weird, if I scan my barcode in the new added field and then press update or publish then Wordpress opens a new tab.

However if I just type the number in the field and then update/publish then it doesn't.

So for some reason if I Scan the product and then directly press the update/publish button, then it open a tab, if I then do some other changes like enter an SKU then it does not open another window/tab.

The value doesn't have any special characters other than numbers, so I'm really confused to why Wordpress has this behavior.

I did update my code slightly.